How to force yarn install to use the current version of node
I have a back end and a front end that I'm developing locally. The backend uses node 22 and the front end uses node 21, as specified in their package.json.
I have both versions installed, and I typically just run nvm use for the correct version before running my yarn commands. So for the front end, that's:
nvm use 21 && yarn install && yarn serve

for the front end before running yarn install, and all works fine.
I'm not sure if it's because of a package audit upgrade or because I upgraded to Sequoia recently or whatever, but now this no longer works. This is what I get when I now try to start my front end.

error *****@2.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this
module. Expected version "21.x". Got "22.11.0"

Any thoughts on how I can get yarn to honor the 21 version when I switch to the front end?
Update:
I'm noticing that nvm current says "system" instead of what I make it. I'm trying to figure out why now.

$nvm use 21
Now using node v21.4.0 (npm v10.9.0)
$nvm current
system


Check the version with node -v, and you can also check the one that yarn presumably uses with yarn exec node -v, they shouldn't differ. This looks like XY problem. There is generally no necessity to install odd versions because they are experimental and have compatibility problems that even ones don't have. "engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version" - this is a sign that something went wrong in deps, you omitted ***** so the proper solution couldn't be suggested at this point
